# Logging into a EC2 created from a OVA virtual machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I have a vmware virtual machine that I converted to an .ova file and uploaded to an S3 bucket. I converted it to an ami file and then created an ec2 instance. This all works great but when I log in using:

```
ssh -i mypemfile.pem root@192.168.1.1
```

where the IP is the real external IP address of the ec2, I get a connection refused error. When I use the vm locally I have a username and password that I normally use to get into it. I think the issue is that I didn't have any steps for configuring external access to the system so I appear to be locked out.

Is there anything I can do in the aws command line tool or otherwise to log into this ec2 and fix the user permissions so that I can log in properly? I'd really prefer not to have to upload the 20GB file all over again to set this up properly.

Thanks!

EDIT- I ran the -vvv command in ssh and this is what I see:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug2: resolving "ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
 [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 1.2.3.4 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Security group? Check if you have inbound 22 rule.

Comment: also ssh -vvv can shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I do have an inbound ssh port 22 set up in the security group. I am wondering if I messed it up by not setting up an openssh server in the vm before I uploaded it to aws. Is there a way to get in or fix that mistake? Thanks!

Comment: always check your security groups. If you're not sure, try *  for the ports and see if that fixes it. Dont leave it permanently open like that though

Comment: Thanks, I have ports 22, 80 and 443 open so I think they are set properly in aws but perhaps not ubuntu's firewall in the VM that I converted. I can't access the inside of the ec2 from aws command line tool without having to ssh in, can I?

Comment: What version of ubuntu? Did you add the Key to the authorized key file? AWS uses ubuntu or root to connect to the machine. Here are some more tips on how to troubleshoot the instance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm